# ADF pipeline fails 10% of the time with a Timeout Error

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an ADF pipeline job that runs once a night for approximately 3 to 4 hours. About 10% of the time in the last month, my job fails. I get this error each time:

> ''Type=Microsoft.Azure.Documents.RequestTimeoutException,Message=Request
> timed out. ActivityId: e9fd74da-cfef-4a86-970a-7de173c0935c, Request
> URI: /dbs/Gd0sAA==/colls/Gd0sANfHJAA=/docs, RequestStats: , SDK:
> documentdb-dotnet-sdk/2.5.1 Host/64-bit
> MicrosoftWindowsNT/6.2.9200.0,Source=Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client,''Type=System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException,Message=A
> task was canceled.,Source=mscorlib,'

My job consists of an Azure Data Explorer command which then copies a table from CosmosDB and migrates it to Kusto.
When I get this error in the past, I have rerun the job and it seems to work fine. Do you know what the problem is? It is becoming inconvenient to rerun a 3 to 4 hour job that sporadically fails for an unclear reason.

Answer (score 1):

Change below configurations and then try-

**Batch Size:** The tool defaults to a batch size of 50. If the documents to be imported are large, consider lowering the batch size. Conversely, if the documents to be imported are small, consider raising the batch size.

**Number of Retries on Failure:** Specifies how often to retry the connection to Azure Cosmos DB during transient failures (for example, network connectivity interruption).

**Retry Interval:** Specifies how long to wait between retrying the connection to Azure Cosmos DB in case of transient failures (for example, network connectivity interruption).

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#SQLSeqTarget